# I want to draw a pyramid using this 2 shapes { /\ } in c# but i got an error

Tags: c#, encoding, drawing, console.writeline

Hi i wanna draw a pyramid that look like this

```
                                          /\ 
                                         /  \
                                        /    \
                                       /______\
```

in Microsoft visual studio c# language but it's not working

i used this code in Microsoft visual studio

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("   /\ ");
            Console.WriteLine("  /  \ ");
            Console.WriteLine(" /    \ ");
            Console.WriteLine("/______\ ");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

but it's not working

```
please explain to me if possible why not working why your code is working in other words (what i need to know )
```

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes. Wherever you had "\" change it to "\\". Or (better for this case) just put a `@` character at the start of each string, e.g. `@" /    \ "`

Comment: When describing your problem, please be more descriptive than "it's not working". In this case it's pretty clear what is wrong, but that isn't always the case and including specific behaviors/errors you're seeing helps us help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape backslashes, or use the `@` literal modifier. The backslash is used to do things like specifying a newline "\n", so the compiler needs to be told explicitly when it write it out verbatim

This uses a multiline string literal

```cs
string p = @"
   /\ 
  /  \ 
 /    \ 
/______\ 
";
Console.WriteLine(p);
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences?view=msvc-170) is a full list of characters that require the escape sequence to ensure they are written verbatim

Comment: It worked i like the idea thx

Answer (score 1):

You should escape the backslashes, try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("   /\\    ");
Console.WriteLine("  /  \\   ");
Console.WriteLine(" /    \\  ");
Console.WriteLine("/______\\ ");
```